# login with mobile number via otp through firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In SignUpActivity.java I am taking the mobile number from user and passing it to another intent where the user needs to enter the otp or it gets fill up automatically.This is working fine through my code but I want to make that type of fragment thing by which if user submits the details in SignUpActivity.java then a fragment kind of thing appears as shown in the screenshot for detecting the otp. Please someone say that how to achieve this.[image of the result which I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF85y.jpg)

Comment: You can open a fragment at bottom for that and pass the mob no as argument. What is the actual problem here , you don't know how to implement fragment ?

Comment: Yes actually the thing is that I don't know that how to create it. Moreover, here actually it disables the background means the SignUpActivity. Please help me with both of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can see info of that here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

```
// The test phone number and code should be whitelisted in the console.
String phoneNumber = "some_number";
String smsCode = "some_codes";

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseAuthSettings firebaseAuthSettings = firebaseAuth.getFirebaseAuthSettings();

// Configure faking the auto-retrieval with the whitelisted numbers.
firebaseAuthSettings.setAutoRetrievedSmsCodeForPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, smsCode);

PhoneAuthProvider phoneAuthProvider = PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance();
phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber,
  60L,
  TimeUnit.SECONDS,
  this, /* activity */
  new OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
      // Instant verification is applied and a credential is directly returned.
    }

    ... /* other callbacks */
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a fragment . First add a container in  your layout file .

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

    < 
      ...........  
      />


    //  This is container for your fragment 
    <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/YOU_CONTAINER_ID"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now , create another layout file and java class for fragment. Then write below java code in your activity

```
public static final int FRAGMENT_CODE = 1111;

.....

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("MobNo", YOUR_PHONE_NO_STRING);

MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragment.setTargetFragment(this,FRAGMENT_CODE);
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.YOUR_CONTAINER_ID, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now, to get phone number in your fragment

```
 if (getArguments() != null) {
     String phoneNo = getArguments().getString("MobNo"));
 }
```

Comment: Hi bro, first thanks for helping. Bro, in my SignUpActivity.xml I wrote fragment container. Then, as suggested I created new activity as Otp_Fragment.java and over there I wrote java code. And the last code I wrote on same Otp_Fragment.java. Have I done it correctly??

Comment: Correct ,just extends Otp_fragment with FRGAMENT.

Answer (score 0):

AuthUI gives you that without any code from your side

do that     `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'`  add this line to build.gradle and update to latest version

```
      // Choose authentication providers
        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
      new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build());  // can add more providers in future in that list without breaking existing code
      // Create and launch sign-in intent
      startActivityForResult(
      AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .build(),
    REQUEST_CODE);
```

That is it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui) is the official documentation for that and don't forget to enable phone auth from the console

also you mentioned in a comment that  you don't know fragments so I will  encourage you to learn the android basics first before moving to firebase

**EDIT**

Regarding collection of user info

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String name = user.getDisplayName();
        String phone = user.getPhoneNumber();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
```

**note** if you are authenticating via phone, only `user.getPhoneNumer();` will return a phone number and other methods will return null, and in case of mail authentication `user.getPhoneNumber()` will return null, in practice you should check all of them for nullity before using them somewhere.

Have a good day Rohan

Comment: Hi Abhinav thanks for sharing this beneficial way. Can you please say that as I can see it's just for authentication purpose. But if I want to store data such as name and email id. Then how to make changes to this. Please help with this

Comment: if you're are authentication a user via phone number , you can't get his name and e mail from auth , you have to make him enter these name somewhere , then save id, and if you're authentication him via mail / google / or maybe facebook , you can get these details via auth , provided that he is using correct name in the original account., I am editing this in the answer

Comment: @Rohanverma do you think i answered you question , if not please ask , if yes then may you mark it answered